# FFMPEG with D3D11 hw acceleration: How to copy DirectX texture to OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, directx, directx-11

I'm decoding a video using FFMPEG with the D3D11 video acceleration. I want to display the decoded frames in my GUI, for which I use OpenGL for rendering. I want to avoid copying the decoded frame back to system memory. So my goal is to copy/map the ID3D11Texture2D which I get from FFMPEG directly to an OpenGL texture. There exists an OpenGL extension for this purpose (WGL_NV_DX_interop and WGL_NV_DX_interop2).

However, I don't get it running. Here is my code so far (stripped down):

```
// create texture, to be used later in DirectX
GLuint texture_opengl;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_opengl);
// .. and set the usual parameters for it

// setup WGL_NV_DX_interop extension
AVBufferRef* hw_device_ctx_buffer = decoder_ctx->hw_device_ctx;
AVHWDeviceContext* hw_device_ctx = (AVHWDeviceContext*)hw_device_ctx_buffer->data;
AVD3D11VADeviceContext* hw_d3d11_dev_ctx = (AVD3D11VADeviceContext*)hw_device_ctx->hwctx;
HANDLE device_handle = wglDXOpenDeviceNV(hw_d3d11_dev_ctx->device);

// create intermediate texture
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC pDes{};
ZeroMemory(&pDes, sizeof(pDes));
pDes.Width = frame->width;
pDes.Height = frame->height;
pDes.ArraySize = 1;
pDes.MipLevels = 1;
pDes.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;
pDes.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
pDes.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
pDes.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
pDes.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
pDes.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
pDes.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Texture2D* texture_D3D11;
hw_d3d11_dev_ctx->device->CreateTexture2D(&pDes, NULL, &texture_D3D11);

// connect opengl and directx textures
HANDLE hRegisterObject = wglDXRegisterObjectNV(
    device_handle, texture_D3D11, texture_opengl, GL_TEXTURE_2D, WGL_ACCESS_READ_WRITE_NV
        );

// run loop and display video
while(..)
{
  // read packets from video file and send it to decoder  

  // receive frame from decoder
  avcodec_receive_frame(decoder_ctx, frame);

  // get DirectX objects from frame
  ID3D11Texture2D* hwTexture = (ID3D11Texture2D*)frame->data[0];
  intptr_t texture_array_index = (intptr_t)frame->data[1];

  // copy frame texture to intermediate texture
  hw_d3d11_dev_ctx->device_context->CopySubresourceRegion(
        texture_D3D11, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        hwTexture, texture_array_index,
        NULL
  );

}
```

After copying the contents from the FFMPEG frame to my intermediate texture `texture_directx`, I expect that I can display the data with the OpenGL texture `texture_opengl`. However, this texture is empty. I also don`t see any copy activity in the resource monitor of the GPU.

Anyone out there who has done this or might see an error in my approach?

I left out any consideration of handling the NV12 format. For now, it's sufficient for me to just copy the luminance part of the frame.

Comment: texture_D3D11 contains NV12 data

Comment: I'm aware of this fact. But how can I copy the Y-data from the NV12 texture to single channel texture (DXGI_FORMAT_R8_...)?

Comment: The Map/Unmap (CPU) might be the only option to copy the Y-data only. Otherwise, you can use DirectX 11 Video context to convert from NV12 to RGBA texture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11videocontext-videoprocessorblt

Comment: Good idea, That might do the job. Thanks!

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but did you ever manage to get this to work? I'm trying to do pretty much the exact same thing and would love to know if what you did here was on the right track.

Comment: No progress on this track. I ended up using CUDA doing the same thing (decode video frames on GPU, copy it out from the decoder reserved memory area, wrap an OpenGL texture around it for displaying. This works very decent. I still think a similar approach should be possible with DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment. And too late. But maybe you can report on some of these for posterity.)

Have you tried any of these?

- Enable [debug layers in Direct3D11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps).
- Copy to OpenGL an `ID3D11Texture2D` obtained by other methods (map/upload, render, shader write). If this works then see next item.
- Perhaps the `ID3D11Texture2D` you get from FFmpeg lacks some necessary flag(s). FFmpeg creates `ID3D11Texture2D` (both single and array, but you are already handling array textures) in `hwcontext_d3d11va.c` with

  ```
   .Usage      = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT,
   .BindFlags  = D3D11_BIND_DECODER,   //probably?
   .MiscFlags  = 0,  //probably?
  ```
- Verify you meet all of [`CopySubresourceRegion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-copysubresourceregion). Including "Must have compatible DXGI formats [...]". If not, copy will fail; check return value for errors. Debug layer will tell you the details!
- Try using some `D3D11_BOX` instead of `NULL` for `pSrcBox`.
- Try [`CopyResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-copyresource) instead of `CopySubresourceRegion()`.